# Control the Name Attribute within an ImageButton using code-behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I have an ImageButton which I want to change the NAME attribute of in the code-behind so that I can render the HTML as needed.

The current Rendering is :

```
<input id="MainContent_GridViewTracking_ibOrderDetail_15" class="smIcon" type="image" src="../Images/icons/img_page.png" text="Details" name="ctl00$MainContent$GridViewTracking$ctl17$ibOrderDetail">
```

I would like to control the NAME using code-behind as assign it to track.myID which would result with something like

```
<input id="MainContent_GridViewTracking_ibOrderDetail_15" class="dhIcon" type="image" src="../Images/icons/doc_page.png" text="Details" name="1654874">
```

TIA

Comment: Why not just render an input control with simple text and html and move on ? Why must be ImageButton ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `MyImageButtons.Attributes["name"]=xyz`? Should to the trick. Or you could add any other attribute to it like so: `MyImageButton.Attributes.Add("trackID", xyz)` and use that atribute for whatever you want to use. Or if you don't want to use that other attribute you could use jQuery to grab that other attribute's value and set it as name value.

Comment: MyImageButton.Attributes.Add("trackID", xyz) - Worked perfect in adding a new Attribute which I was able to access via JQuery :)

Answer (score 0):

put **runat="server"** in the html, then you'll have access to it in the codebehind.

like:

```
<input id="MainContent_GridViewTracking_ibOrderDetail_15"
       runat="server"
       class="smIcon" 
       type="image" 
       src="../Images/icons/img_page.png" 
       text="Details" 
       name="ctl00$MainContent$GridViewTracking$ctl17$ibOrderDetail">
```